# Bash input without pausing the script?

Tags: bash, input

In Bash the only way to get a (user) input seems to be to use the read method, which pauses the rest of the script.  Is there any way to receive a command line input (ending with the enter key) without pausing the script. From what I've seen there may be a way to do it with $1 ..?

Comment: It can probably be done but at this point you should stop using a bash script and switch to something more powerful. Personally I'd use C, but perhaps Perl would be a better choice.

Comment: What are you intending to do with the input once you've received it?

Comment: `$1, $2, ...` are the script arguments.

Comment: This definitely has the feel of being an [XY Question](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: @AbhiBeckert, you **can** launch a command in background with `&`, but as @Etan said, whatcha gunna do with it?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I don't think it's an XY Question. Lack of good parallelisation is a major failing of most scripting languages. It truly is a shame Bash doesn't have any clean/simple way to perform a task while also interacting with the user.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert: there are appropriate languages to use for tasks, and inappropriate ones.  We've not been told what Y is, but the question is asking for X, which is inherently something that shells are not suited to.  We can't give good advice on how to achieve Y until we know what it is, but the X sounds like a bad idea — which is the epitome of the XY Question or XY Problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler shells are perfectly capable of X.

Comment: The input is utilized essentially as a mini-command prompt that interacts strictly within the bounds of the script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`read -t0` can be used to probe for input if your process is structured as a loop

```
 #!/bin/bash

 a='\|/-'
 spin()
 {
  sleep 0.3
  a="${a:1}${a:0:1}"
  echo -n $'\e'7$'\r'"${a:1:1}"$'\e'8
 }

 echo 'try these /|\- , dbpq , |)>)|(<( , =>-<'

 echo -n "  enter a pattern to spin:"
 while true
 do
   spin
   if read -t0 
   then
     read a
     echo -n "  using $a enter a new pattern:" 
   fi
 done
```

else you could run one command in the background while promptiong for input in the foreground. etc...

Comment: `+1` for cool spinning patterns :). Check this one too: |)>=<(|(<=>)