# Getting user input during bash script

Tags: bash

I am trying to create my first bash script:

```
echo "What file are we looking for: "
read FILE

while [ 1 ]
do 
    ls -lah | grep $FILE
    sleep 1;
    clear
    
    # Some way to detect user input
    if [ user-input ]
       then
        echo "Input found"
        exit 1;

    fi

done
```

Is there a way to look for user input without pausing the program? When I used `read input` before the if statement, the program stopped until input was...inputted.... The program is supposed to continuously output the file I am look using `ls` and `clear` so I can monitor the size as it grows, but when the user inputs any key stroke the program exits.

Like I said this is my first bash script, I do know python pretty well and understand 'coding' but not bash.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check [Bash input without pausing the script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27772692/bash-input-without-pausing-the-script), seems like a duplicate.
from that link:

read -t0 can be used to probe for input if your process is structured as a loop

```sh
 #!/bin/bash

 a='\|/-'
 spin()
 {
  sleep 0.3
  a="${a:1}${a:0:1}"
  echo -n $'\e'7$'\r'"${a:1:1}"$'\e'8
 }

 echo 'try these /|\- , dbpq , |)>)|(<( , =>-<'

 echo -n "  enter a pattern to spin:"
 while true
 do
   spin
   if read -t0 
   then
     read a
     echo -n "  using $a enter a new pattern:" 
   fi
 done
```

else you could run one command in the background while promptiong for input in the foreground. etc...

Comment: this worked and yes it does seem to be a replicate question! Now I need to find out how to cancel the imputed text because the shell thinks it is a command when the program exits! Thanks

Comment: Not sure what do you mean.